# Very simple ajax add to cart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ok I am trying to wrap my head around how to add something to a cart and have it show in the page without reloading the page.

So I have tried to write something very simple so I can wrap my head around how exactly the logic works and is properly written. In my example I have a `div` in the page for the `session['cart']` and a drop down.

One option with value of 'red' and the other option with value 'blue'. When I select the option with value of 'red', I want 'red' to show in the div located right after body tag in`session['cart']`. When I select the option with value of 'blue', I want 'blue' to show in `session['cart']`.

I am attempting to do this through an `ajax` post to a page called `'cart_update.php'`. I have been struggling with a more advanced model of this for a week and I thought it would be a good idea just to write something simple so i could really understand and learn what is really going on. Any help is really appreciated!

Here is my code and I know its way off. I am just trying to learn.

index.php

```
        <?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin-top: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div align="left" style="display:block;width:200px;height:200px;background:#ccc;border:solid 1px #009966;">Color Chosen<br /><?php echo $_SESSION['cart']; ?></div>

<div align="center"><form method="post" action="">
<select id="color-selection">
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#color-selection").on("change", function(event){
        var color = $("#color-selection").val();
        var add = "add";
        var dataString = {color: color, type: add}; //JSON-formatted string
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "cart_update.php",  
            data: dataString
        });
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my cart_update.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$type = json_decode($_POST['type']);
if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]== $type)
{
    $color = json_decode($_POST['color']);   
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $color;
}
?>
```

Comment: What is not working? What are you trying to achieve? For 1 you never set your variable `color` anywhere.

Comment: nothing happens at all...i have also added + "type=" + add; to dataString

Comment: Can you change your question to what you have? That makes it easier. In the code you have now, there is no value for `color` because you never set it.

Comment: I would change it but it wont let me

Comment: Anyway.. you need to set you variables `color` and `type` with something like `$(this).closest('form').find('input[name="type"]').val();` for type. And replace 'type' for 'color' for your 'color' variable. You need to set them in your click event handler.

Comment: Any help on this at all? I have made edits above to what I currently have and still no results.

Comment: It is still not working? Your question is that your want either 'red' or 'blue' to show in `$_SESSION['cart']`. As far as I can see 'red' or 'blue' should end up in `$_SESSION['cart']`, you just don't see it. Where do you expect to 'see' it?

Comment: @putvande There is a div right after my <body> tag that holds $_SESSION['cart']. That is where I want it to show up.

Comment: The answer is already been given. After your AJAX call you need to update your `div` in order to place your color there.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what's not working when you don't tell us what error/warning you get. You should look into your js-console (with firebug or another debugging tool)

Looking at your code though, I see some things..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add_to_cart").onClick(function(){
         var dataString = "color=" + color;
          $.ajax({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "cart_update.php",  
          data: dataString
          });
    });
});
```

onClick won't work in this context. Use `on()` instead. http://api.jquery.com/on/
The second thing is that you should use JSON-formatted strings when sending data.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add_to_cart").on("click", function(event){
        var dataString = {color: color}; //JSON-formatted string
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "cart_update.php",  
            data: dataString
        });
    });
});
```

In your html you have hidden fields with several forms with defined colors. Instead of that approach I would make a select-list within one form so it would be kind of easy to grab the value of the color, and you wouldn't have to create a new form for each color.

Something like this:

```
<select id="color-selection">
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Then in your js, you can get the selection of color by doing something like this:

```
color = $("#color-selection").val();
```

To get a response-value when ajax-call is done, then use the done()-callback. It's also a good practice to assign a return-type.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add_to_cart").on("click", function(event){
        color = $("#color-selection").val();
        var dataString = {color: color}; //JSON-formatted string
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "cart_update.php",  
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json" //This indicates the expected return-type
        }).done(function(data) {
                $("#thecoloris").html(data.color); //response from php. Set the color in the div id="thecolorid"
       }); 

    });
});
```

In your php-code you will have to decode the json-data:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=='add')
{
    $color = json_decode($_POST['color']);   
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $color;
}
echo $_POST['color']; //Output color (that is sent to this php through ajax) - This acts as the return value data in the ajax-function done()
?>
```

Usually the outputted value should be encoded in json-format with json_encode($variable) but in this case $_POST['color'] is already in json-format because it was sent to the php from js in json-format.

Comment: ok i changed $(".add_to_cart").on("click", function(event){ to $("#color-selection").on("click", function(event){ and used your code above and still nothing. I am using firebug with no errors and posts are successful to cart_update.php

Comment: @smitty - what do you want to happen? The only thing it should do is set the session 'cart' to the selected color when user clicks on submit.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I just made edits above to current code that I have with your suggestions. What i want to happen is the string "red" to show where <?php echo $_SESSION['cart']; ?> is in index.php or blue to show if i choose blue.

Comment: @smitty - So bascially if user selects a specific color, you want to set a session and then show what color has been chosen for the user somwwhere on the page?

Comment: yes exactly...i am just trying to do something simple so i can figure out how it works. I want logic to be php, jquery post to ajax and show change on same page.

Comment: changed code above again to what I now have...it has to be close...what am I missing?

Comment: @smitty - You have to define when the ajax-call is done with done() and it's a good practice to always to define a return-type even if it is not strictly neccessary. Look at updated answer.

Comment: so am i posting the type 'add' properly? Also if I do echo $_POST['color'];//Output color how do I receive that data and make it equal $_SESSION['cart'] that is in my index.php page?

Comment: $_SESSION['cart'] is being echoed in the very first div after my body tag